# PostgreSQL - ORDER BY with LIMIT not using indexes as expected

Tags: postgresql

We have two tables - `event_deltas` and `deltas_to_retrieve` - which both have BTREE indexes on the same two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE event_deltas
(
  event_id     UUID REFERENCES events(id) NOT NULL,
  version      INT NOT NULL,
  json_patch   JSONB NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_id, version)
);

CREATE TABLE deltas_to_retrieve(event_id UUID NOT NULL, version INT NOT NULL);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX event_id_version ON deltas_to_retrieve (event_id, version);
```

In terms of table size, `deltas_to_retrieve` is a tiny lookup table of ~500 rows. The `event_deltas` table contains ~7,000,000 rows. Due to the size of the latter table, we want to limit how much we retrieve at once. Therefore, the tables are queried as follows:

```
SELECT ed.event_id, ed.version
FROM deltas_to_retrieve zz, event_deltas ed
WHERE zz.event_id = ed.event_id
  AND ed.version > zz.version
ORDER BY ed.event_id, ed.version
LIMIT 5000;
```

Without the `LIMIT`, for the example I'm looking at the query returns ~30,000 rows.

What's odd about this query is the impact of the `ORDER BY`. Due to the existing indexes, the data comes back in the order we want with or without it. I would rather keep the explicit `ORDER BY` there so we're future-proofed against future changes, as well as for readability etc. However, as things stand it has a significant negative impact on performance.

According to [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html):

> An important special case is ORDER BY in combination with LIMIT n: an explicit sort will have to process all the data to identify the first n rows, but if there is an index matching the ORDER BY, the first n rows can be retrieved directly, without scanning the remainder at all.

This makes me think that, given the indexes we already have in place, the `ORDER BY` should not slow down the query at all. However, in practice I'm seeing execution times of ~10s with the `ORDER BY` and <1s without. I've included the plans outputted by `EXPLAIN` below:

**Without ORDER BY**

Just `EXPLAIN`:

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=0.56..20033.38 rows=5000 width=20)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..331980.39 rows=82859 width=20)
        ->  Seq Scan on deltas_to_retrieve zz  (cost=0.00..9.37 rows=537 width=20)
        ->  Index Only Scan using event_deltas_pkey on event_deltas ed  (cost=0.56..616.66 rows=154 width=20)
              Index Cond: ((event_id = zz.event_id) AND (version > zz.version))
```

More detailed `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=0.56..20039.35 rows=5000 width=20) (actual time=3.675..2083.063 rows=5000 loops=1)
"  Buffers: shared hit=1450 read=4783, local hit=2"
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..1055082.88 rows=263260 width=20) (actual time=3.673..2080.745 rows=5000 loops=1)
"        Buffers: shared hit=1450 read=4783, local hit=2"
        ->  Seq Scan on deltas_to_retrieve zz  (cost=0.00..27.00 rows=1700 width=20) (actual time=0.022..0.307 rows=241 loops=1)
              Buffers: local hit=2
        ->  Index Only Scan using event_deltas_pkey on event_deltas ed  (cost=0.56..619.07 rows=155 width=20) (actual time=1.317..8.612 rows=21 loops=241)
              Index Cond: ((event_id = zz.event_id) AND (version > zz.version))
              Heap Fetches: 5000
              Buffers: shared hit=1450 read=4783
Planning Time: 1.150 ms
Execution Time: 2084.647 ms
```

**With ORDER BY**

Just `EXPLAIN`:

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=0.84..929199.06 rows=5000 width=20)
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.84..48924145.53 rows=263260 width=20)
        Merge Cond: (ed.event_id = zz.event_id)
        Join Filter: (ed.version > zz.version)
        ->  Index Only Scan using event_deltas_pkey on event_deltas ed  (cost=0.56..48873353.76 rows=12318733 width=20)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.28..6178.03 rows=1700 width=20)
              ->  Index Only Scan using event_id_version on deltas_to_retrieve zz  (cost=0.28..6173.78 rows=1700 width=20)
```

More detailed `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=0.84..929199.06 rows=5000 width=20) (actual time=4457.770..506706.443 rows=5000 loops=1)
"  Buffers: shared hit=78806 read=1071004 dirtied=148, local hit=63"
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.84..48924145.53 rows=263260 width=20) (actual time=4457.768..506704.815 rows=5000 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: (ed.event_id = zz.event_id)
        Join Filter: (ed.version > zz.version)
"        Buffers: shared hit=78806 read=1071004 dirtied=148, local hit=63"
        ->  Index Only Scan using event_deltas_pkey on event_deltas ed  (cost=0.56..48873353.76 rows=12318733 width=20) (actual time=4.566..505443.407 rows=1813438 loops=1)
              Heap Fetches: 1814767
              Buffers: shared hit=78806 read=1071004 dirtied=148
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.28..6178.03 rows=1700 width=20) (actual time=0.063..2.524 rows=5000 loops=1)
              Buffers: local hit=63
              ->  Index Only Scan using event_id_version on deltas_to_retrieve zz  (cost=0.28..6173.78 rows=1700 width=20) (actual time=0.056..0.663 rows=78 loops=1)
                    Heap Fetches: 78
                    Buffers: local hit=63
Planning Time: 1.088 ms
Execution Time: 506709.819 ms
```

I'm not very experienced at reading these plans, but it's obviously thinking that it needs to retrieve everything, sort it and then return TOP N, rather than just grabbing the first N using the index. It's doing a `Seq Scan` on the smaller `deltas_to_retrieve` table rather than an `Index Only Scan` - is that the problem? That table is v. small (~500 rows), so I wonder if it's just not bothering to use the index because of that?

Postgres version: 11.12

Comment: Start by running `VACUUM ANALYZE` on both tables.

Comment: BTW: theoretically the `deltas_to_retrieve` could be UNIQUE on `event_id`.

Comment: Yeah, the `UNIQUE` doesn't help the performance though. In practice, this is a temporary table created just for this query, so having the index be unique doesn't give us any benefits.

Comment: Can we see `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output?

Comment: Sure thing, I've updated my OP to include these

Comment: Your two "with ORDER BY" plans are fundamentally different from each other.  What changed between them?

Comment: Upgrading to v13, where incremental sort was added, has a good chance of solving this.

Comment: Hmm, I've re-run the simple `ANALYZE` one and updated the OP with what it shows now. Not sure what happened there tbh - maybe tainted by me running it without the index before adding it on? 

In any case, timings are still the same. If an upgrade is the answer then that's... disappointing!

Comment: The fraction of  buffers-hit is very low. What are your shared buffers expected_cahe_size sittings, and how many available memory do you have? [also: the index could be bloated] A good check for memory trashing is: running `vmstat 1` from a different terminal while the query is running.

Comment: Bumping to Postgres 13 does indeed fix it! If you post it an an answer jjanes I can mark it as accepted and include the new query plan that shows what it's doing differently :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to Postgres 13 fixed this for us, with the introduction of incremental sort. From some docs on the feature:

> Incremental sorting: Sorting is a performance-intensive task, so every improvement in this area can make a difference. Now PostgreSQL 13 introduces incremental sorting, which leverages early-stage sorts of a query and sorts only the incremental unsorted fields, increasing the chances the sorted block will fit in memory and by that, improving performance.

The new query plan from `EXPLAIN` is as follows, with the query now completing in <500ms consistently:

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=71.06..820.32 rows=5000 width=20)
  ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=71.06..15461.82 rows=102706 width=20)
"        Sort Key: ed.event_id, ed.version"
        Presorted Key: ed.event_id
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..6659.05 rows=102706 width=20)
              ->  Index Only Scan using event_id_version on deltas_to_retrieve zz  (cost=0.28..1116.39 rows=541 width=20)
              ->  Index Only Scan using event_deltas_pkey on event_deltas ed  (cost=0.56..8.35 rows=190 width=20)
                    Index Cond: ((event_id = zz.event_id) AND (version > zz.version))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:

- [Start by running VACUUM ANALYZE on both tables]
- since `deltas_to_retrieve` only needs to contain the lowest versions, it could be unique on `event_id`
- you can simplify the query to:

---

```
SELECT event_id, version
FROM event_deltas ed
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM deltas_to_retrieve zz
        WHERE zz.event_id = ed.event_id
        AND zz.version < ed.version
        )
ORDER BY event_id, version
LIMIT 5000;
```

Comment: I don't really see how this is simpler - IMO it's harder to read. In any case, it takes even longer to run than the straight join, unfortunately. It is now using the two indexes, but the query plan has it doing an expensive Merge Semi Join. It takes about 20 seconds to run this, vs 10 seconds for the straight join. And removing the `ORDER BY` in this version of the query actually makes it return stuff in a jumbled order.

Comment: It is easier to read because you *know* that only tuples from one table will be selected. In the JOIN version (or the ugly **,** version ) there could be a partial carthesian product being produced.